# I typed the wrong information into my httpd.conf for my WAMP installation ...

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wamp

I just installed WAMP on my 64 Bit Windows 8.1 operating system. I changed a portion of my httpd.conf file that apparently was in error. I tried to follow instructions from a YouTube video and I really do not know much about WAMP or PHP. I am just trying to get started. How do I have to change the information below so that I can get Wamp to work properly.

I just installed it and since it was not working I followed some common advice I found online and tried to make some changes but nothing happened.

I also see there is a httpd.conf.build file that has disparate information from the httpd.conf file itself.

If I just installed WAMP on Windows 8.1 and only made the changes I have shared below ... how do I get my local server working so that I can test out PHP software on my local drive.

I really do not know what to do. I am just starting out with PHP and I cannot even get the WAMP to run when it is supposed to be an automatic installation.

I think I am asking the question in the right place because I made some custom problems for myself so I cannot imagine anyone else asked this exact same question. How did I mess up and how can I get my WAMP installation to run if I just installed it and only made the changes I am outlining below from the original file.

```
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78
Listen 0.0.0.0
Listen 8888

80 Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
```

Comment: Remove `Listen 8888` restart the Apache server and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is what that section of the httpd.conf file should look like

```
#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80

#
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
```

Until you know what you are doing can I suggest that you make a backup copy of any config files before you attempt to change them.

If you really want to move APache to Listen on port 8888, and I suggest you dont. Instead work out what else is using port 80 and reconfigure that.

But if you must then try these changes to httpd.conf

```
#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
Listen [::0]:8080

#
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
```

Then find the line

```
ServerName localhost:80
```

and change it to

```
ServerName localhost:8080
```

Comment: I think **Skype** and **Team Viewer** are the applications I always need to configure to *not* grab port 80. Another one might be IIS if you have that running.

Comment: `netstat -aon` will list ports in use and the PID using it.